# Ionic App and Sails js Sockect client Problems

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sails.js

Am developing ionic App for android wrapped in crosswalk. I have sails js socket client SDK. when I run the app on a real device without connection to the server it launches successfully then throws this error and crashes

```
the connection to the server was unsuccessful(file://android_asset/www/index.html)
```

However when there is connection to the server everything is ok. Am thinking as sockets is trying to establish connection and fails that is causing the crash. How can I avoid this menace ? Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your App timing out. You can either increase the time-out time, but will only reduce the frequency of the issue, or you can:

1. Rename your index.html to “main.html”
2. Create a new “index.html” and put the following content into it:

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>    <title>title</title>
>    <script>
>      window.location='./main.html';
>    </script>
>   <body>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

3. Rebuild your app! No more errors!

Another good idea is to give your application a “splash screen”, so that the user gets instant feedback that your app is loading/working, before it is fully ready.

Comment: I have realized the problem is caused when am loading a script online and the device has no internet connection ... so I think I should check if the device has internet or not ...  Nway thanks for the answer